# Hide page header on both index and author pages

Tags: conditional-tags, headers, author-template

I'm using the Roots theme which is tricky to start with. I'm trying to hide the page headers from both index and author pages. I got to do it on index by using the following code:

```
<?php if(!is_front_page() ){ ?>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>
    <?php echo roots_title(); ?>
  </h1>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

But when I try to add a second conditional to hide it also on author, it doesnt work. This is what I tried:

```
<?php if(!is_front_page() || !is_author() ) { ?>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>
    <?php echo roots_title(); ?>
  </h1>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!
Eric

Comment: As-written, this is a **PHP/logic** question, and not a *WordPress-specific* question. Your problem is an incorrect logic condition. Conditions **A** and **B** are mutually exclusive, so `if ( ! A || ! B )` will *always* return `true`. Use `if ( ! A && ! B )` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple logic error.  You want to display the header if you're not on the front page AND if you're not on an author page.

```
if(!is_front_page() && !is_author() ) {
```